Why is the threshold term incorporated into the weight vector in linear classifiers?
In the context of linear classifiers, such as the perceptron or logistic regression, I understand that the decision boundary is defined by a linear combination of input features and weights, plus a threshold (or bias term):
z = w * x + θ
I have seen explanations where the threshold θ is brought into the weight vector by defining a new weight w0 = -θ and a new input feature x0 = 1. This allows the decision boundary to be written more compactly as:
z = w0 * x0 + Σ(wi * xi)
I am trying to understand the motivation and advantages of this reformulation. Why is the threshold incorporated into the weight vector in this manner? What are the mathematical or computational benefits of doing so?
Actually, my main question is that after changing z function from z=Σ(wi * xi) to z = w0 * x0 + Σ(wi * xi) the definition of unit step function didn't change and it gives 1 if z>0. Is it true? Why?
reference: python Machine learning by Sebastian Raschka and Vahid MirjaLili page 21
